# Define a DEC algorithm for a problem

Tags: pseudo-random-function

> Given $F$ , a PRF family and $F_{n,k}$ a permutation over the set $\{0,1\}^n$. In addition, each permutation (as usual for PRF) and their inverse (not usual) has an efficient calculation.
>
> Define:
>   $M_n=\{0,1\}^{n/2}$
>   $K_n=C_n=\{0,1\}^n$
>
> in addition to that, $ENC_n(k,m;r)=F_{n,k}(r,m)$ when $r$ belongs to $\{0,1\}^{n/2}$.
>
> 1. Propose a DEC algorithm that will suffice correctness.
> 2. Prove that the encryption scheme provides CPA security.

I need help please with understanding the question.
Also, a construction of how to do it will be pleased.

### What I've tried

i've had unsuccessful attempts with understanding exactly how my DEC algorithm should look like at 1.

To answer 1, I must show that Pr(DEC(k,ENC(k,m;r))=m)=1. for a designed DEC. i had two main problems.

1. How does the ENC algorithm return a cypher text in length 'n', with a key and message with length 'n/2'. It seems like it's using some "addition func" with the bits.
2. Writing a valid DEC algorithm. i was thinking using the inverse function of 'F' to get 'm' and 'k' with the DEC algorithm, but there was no success.

Comment: You might mean a PRP family instead?

Comment: It says PRF. how would you approach it if it was a PRP?